# Laravel 5.6 cache issue on Vagrant machine

Tags: laravel, vagrant

**Stack Envionment:**

```
Laravel 5.6
Homestead: 8.2.1
Vagrant: 2.2.7 
PHP: 7.3.9
IDE: Phpstorm 2019.2.3
```

**Problem**: Cache is not clearing when i try to run every cache clear command such as:

```
php artisan optimize:clear
php artisan cache:clear
php artisan optimize
```

Please note: I have tried every single cache clear command avaliable, also deleted vendor and reinstalled and it still points to the previous vendor installed...

**How i noticed:** Currently trying to just test a job in tinker and dispatching the job as a Queue. Then checking the output.

For example:

```
<?php

namespace App\Jobs;

use Illuminate\Bus\Queueable;
use Illuminate\Queue\SerializesModels;
use Illuminate\Queue\InteractsWithQueue;
use Illuminate\Contracts\Queue\ShouldQueue;
use Illuminate\Foundation\Bus\Dispatchable;

class foo implements ShouldQueue
{
    use Dispatchable, InteractsWithQueue, Queueable, SerializesModels;


    public function __construct(){}

    public function handle(){ echo 'bar';}
}
```

Dispatching this job will echo `foo` but when i change it to `bar`, it will still echo `foo`.

Currently having to run `vagrant reload` which solves the issue, but i need to keep doing this for upon every job class change.

**Homestead.yml**

```
ip: 192.168.10.12
version: 8.2.1
memory: 2048
cpus: 1
provider: virtualbox
authorize: ~/.ssh/id_rsa.pub
keys:
    - ~/.ssh/id_rsa
folders:
    -
        map: /Users/user/Sites/test-package
        to: /home/vagrant/code
sites:
    -
        map: homestead.test
        to: /home/vagrant/code/public
        php: "7.3"
databases:
    - homestead
name: test-package
hostname: test-package
```

**Driver Settings**

```
# Driver Settings
BROADCAST_DRIVER=log
CACHE_DRIVER=file
SESSION_DRIVER=file
SESSION_LIFETIME=120
QUEUE_DRIVER=database
```

Comment: How do you run the jobs?

Comment: Running `Queue::push ( new App\Job\Foo )` in tinker.  I have been doing this on all other projects and it was working fine. @mrhn

Comment: I meant which driver :) sync, db, redis?

Comment: Updated and pasted it there :), i am using database

Comment: You write here your db is QUEUE_DRIVER=database, that is not sync?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To update your queue jobs with changes you can run.

```
php artisan queue:restart
```